# Specify Mac address in gce

Tags: linux, mac, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to specify mac address in a Google compute engine instance; I am moving a legacy java software which has a licence bound to the Mac of eth0. OS is now centos7.
I tried with ifconfig but lost connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support: [...] I can confirm it's not currently possible to change the MAC address of the main interface. We have feature requests to make MAC address configurable and also to simply show MAC address in the API.[...]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have specific experience with GCE, but knowing Virtualization I would doubt this is possible. MAC Addresses are hardware addresses of NICs and on VMs are specified in the VM config outside of the OS. When you changed the ifcfg file to have a different MAC address, it tried to bind that config to a device with that address but of course couldn't find one matching so it failed.

Comment: Hi Joe, it could be possible to specify the MAC with an gcloud API call, not necessarily inside the VM. But I haven't found anything so far..

Comment: Seems like you could ask GCE support for help. They should be best positioned to tell you if it's possible and/or do it for you:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/filereport

Comment: Already did, will post answer here.